# LIKE does not support collation: en-ci-rtrim

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to do a simple Snowflake query as such:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE NAME_COLUMN LIKE '%ABC%'
```

Yet I'm getting the following error.

```
SQL compilation error: error line 17 at position 12 Function LIKE does not support collation: en-ci-rtrim.
```

What is the work around here? I don't have the ability to alter the underlying table or the collation attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-colate in real time:

```sql
create or replace temp table collation_demo (
  uncollated_phrase varchar, 
  stack_phrase varchar collate 'en-ci-rtrim'
  );

insert into collation_demo (uncollated_phrase, stack_phrase) 
   values ('pinata', 'pirata');
   
select *
from collation_demo
where collate(stack_phrase, 'en') like '%pi%'
order by stack_phrase
```

If you remove the `collate()` call around `stack_phrase` you'll get the same error. But with it, the query works as expected.

Another workaround is to use a different string comparing function that supports the existing collation. For example, `contains()`:

```sql
select *
from collation_demo
where contains(stack_phrase, 'PI');
```

Works!

Comment: is there a not* contains function?

Comment: I have a similar situation with a column with 'en-ci' collation.  I can use LIKE but not RLIKE or REGEXP:  `select * from dumpster
where collate( dump_loc, 'en') RLIKE 'MILLCRUSH[12]';` Apparently there is something I don't understand.  This is also in a Snowflake context.

Comment: Eric - new question please! With sample data and desired results

Comment: Felipe - thanks for the guidance (I'm very new here).  I found the solution by using `collate(offending_column, '')`.  I will try posting my first question next time.  Cheers!